# Reflexive subspaces of dual spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

If $X$ is a Banach space, is it true that $X^{*}$ must contain an infinite dimensional reflexive subspace? I know of Gowers' example of a Banach space not containing $c_0$, $l_1$, or reflexive, but I cannot tell if it is a dual space.

Comment: $\ell_1$ is a dual space and contains no infinite dimensional reflexive subspace.

Comment: Ah, of course, thank you. Is it known whether Gowers' space not containing $c_0$, $l_1$, or reflexive is a dual space?

Comment: Yes, it has a boundedly complete basis, so is isomorphic to a dual space.  This is mentioned in the first paragraph of $$ $$ Argyros, Spiros A.; Arvanitakis, Alexander D.; Tolias, Andreas G. Saturated extensions, the attractors method and hereditarily James tree spaces. Methods in Banach space theory, 1–90, London Math. Soc. Lecture Note Ser., 337, Cambridge Univ. Press, Cambridge, 2006.

Comment: That answers my questions, than you for the reference.